# WC()->cart and functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I get this error when adding this code to functions.php

**Fatal error: Call to a member function calculate_totals() on a non-object**

This is the code generating the error

```
WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
$packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
```

However when i put this code in header.php & footer.php no error and `$packages` array is returned.

How do i solve this, i need this code in functions.php?

Comment: In functions.php how are you adding the code? use appropriate hooks or create funtion otherwise it will run before the woocommerce plugin is called

Comment: I've read that plugins are loaded before functions.php?

Comment: Yes, but if you just throw your code in it without using any hook then it will not work. you can use `init` hook for this purpose.

Comment: Ok thanks for help.  I have this code hooked to a function using in `add_action('wp_ajax_refresh_checkout_page', 'refresh_checkout_page');
function refresh_checkout_page() {
 }`  it also doesn't work, why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by simply using `init` hook in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_packages_custom' );

function get_packages_custom() {
   WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
   WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
   $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
}
```

Comment: I copied and paste this and still the same error?  Any idea?

Comment: hmmm, try this: `global $woocommerce; $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();`

Comment: still the same error. I've been pulling my hair out trying to solve this.  Any way to see a list of functions loaded in wordpress?

Comment: If you're following @madforstrength comment, but adding `var_dump($woocommerce); var_dump($woocommerce->cart);` right after the `global $woo...` line. Do you get any output?

Comment: @OfirBaruch yes i do get output for `$woocommerce`.. i get an array but i don't any output for `var_dump($woocommerce->cart);` the value returned is null?

Comment: It's really weird, maybe use `woocommerce_init` as the action hook instead of `init`. But to be honest - I can't think on a reason for why it's not working at the moment.

Comment: I think its because he is trying to call cart in ajax, whereas cart is specific to current user session.

Comment: @madforstrength how do i load the session for the current user? i assumed everything should be loaded.

Comment: Nope not using mysqli_query.  This code causes page break in `functions.php` but on the frontend the $packages array is returned and no page break?  The function my ajax calls in in functions.php.  There must be something being loaded but how do i pinpoint what class or function, which needs to be called?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try enqueing following scripts:
`wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );`
`wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-cart' );`