# woocommerce add to cart function returns error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I made a product and want to add it to the cart and then go to checkout page

```
function redirect_to_gateway() {

    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => 'My post',
        'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_type'     =>'product'
    );

    $product_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    if ( $product_ID ){
        add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', 100 );
        add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', 100 );
        add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock_status', 'instock' );


        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID );
        exit( wp_redirect(wc_get_checkout_url()) );

    }
```

}

but this line of code:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID );
```

returns an error every time and I can't add product to cart

this is the error code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add_to_cart() on null in

Comment: please try add_composite_to_cart() function instead of add_to_cart()

Comment: there is no add_composite_to_cart function in woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this function on a hook? Perhaps this would be helpful: [WC()->cart and functions.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671984/wc-cart-and-functions-php)

Comment: yes i run this on a hook. add_action('admin_post_redirect_to_gateway','redirect_to_gateway');
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_redirect_to_gateway','redirect_to_gateway');